# Compare and filter data from files in C#

Tags: c#, network-programming

I have two files. First containing ca. 20 lines.

```
202    0021.ccc1.2e3b    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/31
202    0023.246b.dd96    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/16
202    0023.246e.2e41    DYNAMIC     Gi2/0/16
```

the other(I blacked out the IPs, estimate 1000 lines):

```
Internet  172.ZZ.XX.01           1   0021.ccc1.2e3b  ARPA   VlanXXX
Internet  172.ZZ.XX.02           0   0023.246e.2e41 ARPA   VlanXXX
Internet  172.ZZ.XX.03           3   0023.246b.dd96  ARPA   VlanXXX
```

Now I need to merge those two files that I get the port, the MAC and the IP:

```
172.ZZ.XX.03 0023.246b.dd96 Gi2/0/16
172.ZZ.XX.02 0023.246e.2e41 Gi1/0/16
172.ZZ.XX.01 0021.ccc1.2e3b Gi1/0/31
```

So basically I need to go through the first file and find the equivalent by MAC in the second file. Then print/output these three values.

I tried it with Dictionaries and Hashtables, but its complicated and I'm kind of stuck. Is there an easy way to accomplish this task?

Additionaly complicating is the fact that in the 1st file, one interface/port may occur more than once and in the second, there can be more than one time the same MAC.

edit: request of my attempt

I put every line in a List (first file is TargetSwitch, 2nd CoreSwitch), then calling InitHashtable to put the data in two hashtables. After that I find the Matches in a funky way by iterating through the hashtable. The Ports meight also not be correct because it takes the first which correspondents to the mac-Adress

```
private void InitHashtable()
    {
        foreach (string line in ListEntryTargetSwitch)
        {
            htTargetSwitch.Add(line.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1], line.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[3]);
        }

        foreach (string line in ListEntryCoreSwitch)
        {
            if (line.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[3] != "Incomplete")
            {
                htCoreSwitch.Add(line.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1], line.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[3]);
            }

        }
    }

    private void FindMatches()
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_txtResult3, false);


        foreach (string mac in htCoreSwitch.Values)
        {
            if (htTargetSwitch[mac] != null)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(mac + " " + htTargetSwitch[mac] + " " + htCoreSwitch.Keys.OfType<string>().FirstOrDefault(s => htCoreSwitch[s] == mac));
            }

        }
        sw.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Show your attempts please.

Comment: This looks like a task for [LogParser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx). Query samples can be found at [LogParser rocks!](http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/log-parser-rocks-more-than-50-examples/).

Comment: I added my attempt. Could you go a little deeper in LogParser thing. I don't really get it.

Comment: LogParser should allow you to query your logfiles like a database and could save you from parsing the data yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've get somthing like this

```
class r1
{
  public  String f1, f2, f3, f4;

    public r1(string line)
    {
        //TODO: Parse line to fields
    }
}

class r2
{
    public String f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6;

    public r2(string p)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }
}

class r3
{
    public String f1, f2, f3;

    public String ToString()
    {
        //TODO: Implement
        return String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", f1, f2 ,f3);
    }
}

class c1
{        
    public static void main()
    {
        String path1 = "file1.txt";
        Dictionary<String, r1> file1_parsed = new Dictionary<string, r1>();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path1);
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            String line = sr.ReadLine();
            r1 record = new r1(line);
            file1_parsed.Add(record.f2, record);
        }
        sr.Close();
        String path2 = "file2.txt";
        String path3 = "file3.txt";
        sr = new StreamReader(path2);
        StreamWriter result_file = new StreamWriter(path3);
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            r2 record = new r2(sr.ReadLine());
            result_file.WriteLine(new r3 {
                f1=record.f2,
                f2=record.f4,
                f3=file1_parsed[record.f4].f4
            });
        }
        sr.Close();
        result_file.Flush();
        result_file.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these step:

Define an class `c1` which contains all information from a single line in line1.
Same for a line in file2, will result in class `c2`

Parse all lines from file1 into a list of `c1`
Parse all line form file2 into a lst of `c2`

Build a dictionary with key MAC number from your `c1` objects.

Now loop through your `c1` objects, find the matching `c2` object in the dictionary using the MAC number, and print out all required info from `c1`and matching `c2`

Comment: ... classes -.- i feel pretty stupid now :) a already tought of 2D arrays. but yeah, classes. Ty